# Bind qTip to Kendo Widget

Tags: kendo-ui, qtip, qtip2

I have this:

```
<input id="numeric" title="Numeric Tooltip" type="number" min="0" max="100" />
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
$("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox();
```

then

```
$('#numeric').qtip({
    content: {
        text: $(this).prop("title")
    }
});
```

How do I bind these 2 items to the same element?

http://jsfiddle.net/uZUjK/167/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add the scripts and styles.

Then apply the qtip to the **wrapper** element of the numeric textbox - because the input element itself is not visible all the time and the tooltip will also not be visible. I updated your fiddle to cover these requirements

```
var kendoNum = $("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox().data('kendoNumericTextBox');
kendoNum.wrapper.qtip({
    content: {
        text: kendoNum.element.prop("title")
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uZUjK/170/) is updated version of the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Input fields in KendoUI are decorated with other HTML elements in order to make them compatible across browser. Your original `input` is hidden by another `input` that does not have `numeric` id.

Use:

```
$('#numeric').closest(".k-input-wrapper").qtip({
    content: {
        text: $(this).prop("title")
    }
});
```

instead.

**NOTE**: And don't forget to include `qtip` [script](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.0.0/basic/jquery.qtip.min.js) and [style](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.0.0/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css).